# Why did iMessage stop working after upgrading to iOS 8.2?

Tags: messages, software-update, ios

After updating to iOS 8.2 I got a message saying "Your SIM sent a text message." Then I tried to send someone an iMessage and it sent an SMS instead even though that person is able to send and receive iMessages.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6866832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the message is for security purposes(citation?) and for some reason it turned my iMessage off. Turning it back on fixed all my issues.